# Is there a way to use WinSCP from Visual Studio to transfer files to a target (Linux) device

Tags: visual-studio, winscp, ntvs

Is it possible to integrate WinSCP (or equivalent) with Visual Studio 2015, so that any of my node edits can be first transferred to my target Linux (embedded) device and then start up a remote debug session (using NTVS's RemoteDebug.js)?

I do manual versions of this process using WinSCP or via git repo. I wish I could publish to an embedded target and start debugging all from within Visual Studio.